# hh_client reports errors on package

Tags: composer-php, hhvm, hacklang

I am following the instruction in [Getting started](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/getting-started/starting-a-real-project) on official Hacklang website.

As it says, I run:

```
$ touch .hhconfig
$ mkdir bin src tests
$ cat > hh_autoload.json
{
  "roots": [
    "src/"
  ],
  "devRoots": [
    "tests/"
  ],
  "devFailureHandler": "Facebook\\AutoloadMap\\HHClientFallbackHandler"
}
$ composer require hhvm/hsl hhvm/hhvm-autoload
```

Then I run `hh_client`, which throws 74 errors like those:

```
Typing[4110] You cannot use HH_FIXME or HH_IGNORE_ERROR comments to suppress error 4110
   --> vendor/autoload.hack
318 |   \HH\autoload_set_paths(/* HH_FIXME[4110] incorrect hhi */ $map, Generated\root());
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Typing[4110] Invalid argument
   --> vendor/autoload.hack
318 |   \HH\autoload_set_paths(/* HH_FIXME[4110] incorrect hhi */ $map, Generated\root());
    |                                                             ^^^^
   --> /private/tmp/hh_server/hhi_3f14b466/functions.hhi
 82 |     KeyedContainer<string, KeyedContainer<string, string>> $map,
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Expected KeyedContainer<string, string>
   --> vendor/hhvm/hhvm-autoload/src/FailureHandler.hack
 46 |   final public function handleFailure(string $kind, string $name): void {
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ But got (function(string $kind, string $name): void)

Naming[2050] You cannot use HH_FIXME or HH_IGNORE_ERROR comments to suppress error 2050
   --> vendor/bin/hh-autoload.hack
179 |   GenerateScript::main(vec(/* HH_IGNORE_ERROR[2050] */ $GLOBALS['argv']));
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

...
```

Those errors are related to hh_autoload and hsl package installed through composer.

Why is it???

Answer (score 3):

The Hack typechecker recently ([as of HHVM 4.62](https://hhvm.com/blog/2020/06/16/hhvm-4.62.html)) changed from 'allow by default' to 'ban by default' for error codes in HH_FIXME comments.

Try adding this to your `.hhconfig`:

```
allowed_fixme_codes_strict = 2050, 4110
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue even after having tried this